# Enum in Activity

Tags: android

I have trouble understanding the following thing: in my localized application I have an `Enum` in an activity that stores some localized strings (`R.string.aString`) which are compared against another localized string.

If while in application I change the locale and I came back and start the Activity that contains the Enum  I observe that it's members have are the same as before localization change.

What is the reason for this?

Edit :

```
class Settings extends Activity 
{

    public enum SettingPreferenceScreen
    {
        Connection (R.string.Connection , xml_resource_1)
        Legend (R,string.Legend ,xml_resource_2)
        .......

    String key;
    int res;

    SettingPreferenceScreen(String key, int res)
    {....}

    public int getResource (String key)
    {
      for(SettingPreferenceScreen p : SettingPreferenceScreen.values())
        if(key.equals(p.key))
           return p.res;

      return -1;
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please, add a relevant snippet of code so that we can give you a concrete answer.

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing in that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try [avoiding Enums](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/practices/design/performance.html#avoid_enums) when you develop for android.

Second, my guess is that the Enum get created on the `onCreate()` method
of your `Activity` and when you open the application for the second time that method is not called. Check the [Activity's lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife).

Comment: No..that why I'm surprised too.

Comment: Enums are great for readability, and enables us to make cool designs. The "avoid enums" tip on Android developers website is in "Design for performance" category, so you don't have to avoid them when you want to code the elegant 80% of your app.
Second, Enum can't be created in some class's method, they are initialized when they are loaded by class loader. What you can do in your Activity is only assign different instances of the Enum object to the Enum reference.

Comment: Avoiding enums is no longer part of the referenced performance guidelines. This suggests that the advice was incorrect or that Enum performance is no longer poor in Dalvik

Answer (score 2):

`R.string` does not contain strings, it contains resource ID constants. (Auto-generated `int` values.) These IDs will be the same regardless of the configuration. The ID constants are used to fetch application resources from a [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) object (or from a `Context`, which calls through to your `Resources`). When you call `getString` or similar, the system will return the localized resource when applicable.

It seems like you're trying to re-implement functionality that Android already provides for you. Can you give us some more details if this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

Update:
It is not necessary to avoid enums in Android anymore... I don't know when it came but the android sdk now includes proguard which optimizes the code at build time and replaces the enums with int constants (cf. `proguard.cfg`).

Furthermore, the paragraph telling you not to use enums in the dev guide has been removed (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html)